# Is there a way to allow copy and pasting in c++ when someone presses ctrl+v?

Tags: c++, conio

I was making a small text editor in c++ for fun and the code worked, though a bit slow, but when I tried to paste something into the editor, I ran into a problem. When I typed ctrl+v, instead of it pasting the copied text, which was a web link, it showed this: ▬. This happened when I actually pressed ctrl+c or ctrl+s or any letter with ctrl at the beginning to be fair. Why does this happen and is there a way to stop this?

```cpp
int editTxtFile() {
  std::string txtstr;
  std::string filename;
  std::cin >> filename;
  std::ofstream file("TXTFILES\\"+filename+".txt", std::ios::out);
  std::cout << "This is an editor for txt files (sorry for the flashing!)\n";

  char keypressed;
  int asciiVal;
  if (file.is_open()) {
    while (true) {
      keypressed = getch();
      asciiVal = keypressed;
      switch (asciiVal) {
        case 13:
          txtstr += "\n";
          system("cls");
          break;
        case 8:
          txtstr = txtstr.substr(0, txtstr.size() - 1);
          system("cls");
          break;
        case 94:
          file << txtstr;
          system("cls");
          file.close();
          break;
        default:
          txtstr += keypressed;
          system("cls");
          break;
      }
      std::cout << txtstr;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am using the header file conio.h for the getch() function.
How can I fix this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on your console. Not a c++ issue.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 and it is the default conole. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Look for another console. Find a library to control it, like ncurses or something.

Comment: You're not doing anything special with a ctrl+v, so it is handled like a normal character. You need to add a handler for it like you do for 13 (enter) or 8 (backspace). What are you going to do if you want to enter a `'^'` into the file you're editing?

Comment: Standard C++ has no concept of the clipboard. Copy/Paste operations are the responsibility of the Console Terminal to handle.

Comment: "*I am using the header file conio.h for the getch() function.*" - You really shouldn't be use `<conio.h>` in C++. You can replace `getch()` with `cin.get()` instead.